# TCP and UDP packets are ignored after UDP tunnel

Tags: python, networking, tcp, network-programming, udp

I have to encapsulate my packets in an UDP tunnel, and I'm currently trying using python on Ubuntu 22.04. At the end of the tunnel, when I send the deencapsulated packets, they are not considered by the UDP or TCP applications.

At the moment, I’m using a packet socket to read traffic on the sending side and I send the whole packet as an UDP payload:

```py
iface_name = "dummy1"  # interface name
ip_dst = "192.168.1.2"  # IP destination

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(3))
s1.bind((iface_name, 0))
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    packet, _ = s1.recvfrom(65565)
    s2.sendto((packet), (ip_dst, 5556))
```

On the receiving side, I get the UDP payload and send it to the network through a TUN interface:

```py
entering_ip = "192.168.1.2"  # Should be the same as IP destination of encapsulation

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s1.bind((entering_ip, 5556))
tun = open("/dev/net/tun", "r+b", buffering=0)
LINUX_IFF_TUN = 0x0001
LINUX_IFF_NO_PI = 0x1000
LINUX_TUNSETIFF = 0x400454CA
flags = LINUX_IFF_TUN | LINUX_IFF_NO_PI
ifs = struct.pack("16sH22s", b"tun0", flags, b"")
ioctl(tun, LINUX_TUNSETIFF, ifs)
while True:
    packet, _ = s1.recvfrom(65565)
    tun.write(packet[14:])  # the [14:] is to remove the ethernet header
```

As far as I can tell, using wireshark, the packets entering on the `dummy1` interface where I sniff them and the packets exiting the TUN have the same L3 (IP) & L4 (TCP, UDP, ICMP) headers and the same payload. Differences, if any are in the L2 (ethernet) headers.

I have a similar setup to communicate the other way around and can successfully ping an IP after the TUN using the machine on the sender side.

I am **not**, however, able to send any TCP or UDP traffic through this setup as the packets exiting the TUN does not get processed by any receiving application.

What I tried so far:

- Made sure ip_forward is activated on both ends, checked my routes countless times, checked IP and TCP checksum using wireshark which claims they are good.
- Using a raw socket on the receiving end using `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)` instead of the TUN: the packet comes out on `lo` with a src and dest MAC of 00:00:00:00:00:00 and is not seen by my applications bound to another IP / interface.
- Using a packet socket on the receiving end and modifying the src and dest MAC addresses in the ethernet header. Even the ping stop working in this case.
- Using a TAP instead of the TUN on the receiving end. Keeping the original ethernet header or modifying it had no effect and the ping stopped working as well.
- Using veth to route the received packets further into a netns on the receiving end: packets are visible through the veth interfaces using wireshark, but cannot be seen on the other interface in the netns where an application is listening. Binding the application to the veth proved to be impossible as well.

When using a TCP application on the receiving end, I have no answer to the SYN packet. Neither a RST nor a SYN/ACK.

When using an UDP application on the receiving end, no messages get received by the application.

What's stopping my packets from being processed?

Comment: You need to post a [mre]. There's no way we can tell what you might be doing wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the comment, I added the code. As I thought it was layer 3 related, I wasn't sure the code was relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but without explanation.

To make it work, I replaced the reading socket `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)`, with another tun interface. I read the packet on a tun, and write on another one. As I said, I have no idea why my first solution doesn't work, but as long as it works, I'm happy.